# How do I avoid floating point rounding errors in WebVTT?

Tags: floating-point, accessibility, video.js, webvtt, closed-captions

I'm trying to build a WebVTT metronome and I'm specifying the cues with millisecond precision for both the start and end times. Unfortunately, it is showing up inconsistently in different browsers. Some of the beats start late, some are missed, and some overlap with the next one.

I believe it is a browser rounding error as `VTTCue.startTime` and `VTTCue.endTime` are [stored by seconds as a double](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VTTCue/VTTCue).

What's weird is that it only works in native Firefox video viewer, which [my guess is due to it's special way of handling floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324792/is-firefox-the-only-browser-that-supports-floating-point-numbers-as-width-declar) also [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567690/firefox-and-javascript-rounding-rules).

I've even tried doing it in Video.js and had the same issues (even in Firefox).

It's all bizarre to me, since my understanding is that [JS numbers are supposed to be 8 bytes long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942516/double-to-byte-array-conversion-in-javascript).

[This is my sample WebVTT and environment](https://zcorpan.github.io/live-webvtt-viewer/#vtt=WEBVTT%0A%0A1%0A00:00:00.500+--%3E+00:00:00.633+line:0%0A0.5%0A%0A2%0A00:00:00.944+--%3E+00:00:01.076+line:0%0A0.9444444444444444%0A%0A3%0A00:00:01.387+--%3E+00:00:01.522+line:0%0A1.3888888888888888%0A%0A4%0A00:00:01.833+--%3E+00:00:01.966+line:0%0A1.8333333333333333%0A%0A5%0A00:00:02.277+--%3E+00:00:02.411+line:0%0A2.2777777777777777%0A%0A6%0A00:00:02.722+--%3E+00:00:02.855+line:0%0A2.7222222222222223%0A%0A7%0A00:00:03.165+--%3E+00:00:03.298+line:0%0A3.166666666666667%0A%0A8%0A00:00:03.611+--%3E+00:00:03.744+line:0%0A3.6111111111111116%0A%0A9%0A00:00:04.054+--%3E+00:00:04.187+line:0%0A4.055555555555556%0A%0A10%0A00:00:04.500+--%3E+00:00:04.633+line:0%0A4.500000000000001%0A%0A11%0A00:00:04.944+--%3E+00:00:05.075+line:0%0A4.9444444444444455%0A%0A12%0A00:00:05.386+--%3E+00:00:05.522+line:0%0A5.38888888888889%0A%0A13%0A00:00:05.833+--%3E+00:00:05.966+line:0%0A5.833333333333335%0A%0A14%0A00:00:06.277+--%3E+00:00:06.410+line:0%0A6.2777777777777795%0A%0A15%0A00:00:06.722+--%3E+00:00:06.855+line:0%0A6.722222222222224%0A%0A16%0A00:00:07.166+--%3E+00:00:07.299+line:0%0A7.166666666666669%0A%0A17%0A00:00:07.610+--%3E+00:00:07.743+line:0%0A7.611111111111113%0A%0A18%0A00:00:08.054+--%3E+00:00:08.188+line:0%0A8.055555555555557%0A%0A19%0A00:00:08.500+--%3E+00:00:08.631+line:0%0A8.500000000000002%0A%0A20%0A00:00:08.944+--%3E+00:00:09.076+line:0%0A8.944444444444446%0A&style=::cue+%7B%0Acolor:+green;%0Afont-size:+55px;%0A%7D%0A)

The beats should be consistently spaced.

Comment: [There's a cue sync issue that has been open for a while](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=576310), but that doesn't explain the issue in Safari